# How can I perform a SELECT from my functions.php in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have had a google about and found a few posts but not a full answer. I want to run my own query when a page is loaded into WordPress. I want to run this query from functions.php:

```
function performSelect() {
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->query("SELECT ip_address FROM MyTABLE ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 0,1"); 

print_r( $result);

}
```

I get a '1' outputting on my page. How do I go about getting ip_address back as an actual field? I have ran the query on the server and it does return an IP, not a 1 as in WordPress!

**UPDATE 1**

I have now have this working, but I'd like to put in a loop for queries that return more than one row:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ip_address FROM MyTABLE ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 0,1", ARRAY_A); 

echo $result['ip_address']; // WORKS
```

How would I go about looping through $result? I've tried a few methods and all error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ip_address FROM MyTABLE ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 0,1");
foreach($result as $row) {
    echo 'Ip address:'.$row->ip_address;
}
```

Comment: I have added an update to my question and have actually asked to do exactly in your example However the echo is blank (other than the first half of course). It doesn't seem to work in a loop?

Comment: Sorry my bad! I had to update get_row to get_results - now it is working! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try get_row:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ip_address FROM MyTABLE ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 0,1");
```

get_row will immediately parse the sql result into a row; you can also assign a second parameter to turn the result into an object, see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Instead of get_row, you can also use get_results to retrieve multiple results from the database.

Comment: Thank you this has got me very close. However I'm now trying to get $result working in a loop with a bit of difficulty.

Comment: you are limiting to 1; you will always get 1 result..?

Comment: Yes you are right. In this case it's true but I wanted to learn the syntax for future queries with more than one record. I have now fixed it. See my comment above. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`$result` isn't a string but a mysqli result, so you need to turn it into an array, then grab the ip address.

```
$result = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
var_dump($result['ip_address'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_var to directly fetch the result:

```
function performSelect() {
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ip_address FROM MyTABLE ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 0,1"); 

    print_r($result);

}
```